# How to pass data into multiple viewcontrollers on a tabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue, tabbarcontroller

I'm redoing the user interface of my app to use tables views and also the tab bar controller to break up the amount of data to enter into 4 logical sections rather than one long scrolling screen of UITextFields and Switches.

Previously I would pass a new managed object into the new view controller using the following code in prepareForSegue:

```
  if ([[segue identifier ] isEqualToString:@"addDiveSite"]) {
    //
    UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;

    AddEditDiveSiteViewController *adsvc = (AddEditDiveSiteViewController *) navController.topViewController;

    adsvc.navigationItem.title=@"Add Site";
```

The view controller is embedded in a navigation controller and I grab it by asking for the topviewcontroller - as there is only one screen.

Now with the tab bar controller I have 4 screens to enter the data on.

I get that I could substitute:

```
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addDiveSite"]){

    UITabBarController *tabController =segue.destinationViewController  ;

    AddEditDiveSiteViewController *adsvc =(AddEditDiveSiteViewController *)[[tabController customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];


DiveSite *newDiveSite =(DiveSite*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DiveSite" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    adsvc.currentSite = newDiveSite;
```

But that only leaves me with the data passed to a property on one of the 4 tabs and I need to have access to it on all 4.

Would the correct approach to be have 4 variants of this:

```
       AddEditDiveSiteViewController *adsvc =(AddEditDiveSiteViewController *)[[tabController customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

One for each of the 4 tabs / objects at index?

Or should I be looking at subclassing UITabBarController and giving it a property to pass the data into and if so whats the format for grabbing a property from the 'parent' UITabBarController?

Or is there a completely different approach?

Thanks for taking the time to read and or respond to this

Edit

Finally went with the following approach which seems to work fine

For the views 2,3 and 4 I grab the UITabBarController they are within and get its array of controllers. Then I get the first item in the array and make a pointer to its property that I need to access.

Simply when you know what to look for.

Hope this helps someone out there

Comment: I'd go with a different approach. The UI described here (having four tabbed view controllers to break up a lengthy view) is awkward and not consistent with the normal use of tabs. How about a single tableview with grouped style (4 groups) like on Contacts? Each group can have little or lots of info, depending on your needs.

Comment: I agree with @MattMartel. Perhaps a navigation controller with a "next" button at the bottom of each table?

Comment: Matt-I'm using grouped tables on the views. 1st view contains all essentials that must be entered before entry can be saved.So its nice that thats presented separately from the optional data.Was at a dev meeting in London pub & most devs there suggested using table views and finding a way to present the info in chunks that weren't off-putting rather than the rather long scroll view I had with all the data on. I've read subclassing UITabBar controller is a no-no. So perhaps i need to,on views 2,3,&4,grab UITabbarControllers array of controllers & make a pointer to the first views data property.

Comment: How about using a single view with a segment controller (or similar) to activate the four groups of info? I'd still avoid using the Tab Controllers to separate out your input fields, that is typically used to distinguish modes of your app.